# Apple Developer membership

Tags: developer-program

I am trying to sign up for Apple Developer membership, and I've enrolled and paid for 1 year.

But after trying to sign in to my developer account, it states that my membership is pending and to complete your enrollment by purchasing the membership.

But I've already bought it and they sent a confirmation email to me.

Does anyone have an idea why it is telling me to complete your enrollment by purchasing the membership?

Comment: how long since you paid?  it may take a while to update.

Comment: "Pending" means not active (or approved?) yet. Give it some time. If you hear nothing after 24 hours contact support.

Answer (score 1):

So i contacted the apple developer 
It seems that even after you purchase the program
It is normal to see to complete your enrollment,complete the purchase when you sign in Developer,
If you receive a confirmation that you bought it,just wait,dont buy it again it might take several days,also they might send email about missing documents